# dynamic container

Tags: html, css

I have a container `<div>`:

```css
.containerBig{
   width:940px; 
}
```

with many small containers in it.

```css
.containerSmall{
   width:auto;
   height:100%;
   float:left;
}
```

looks like this: `[[][][]]`

The small containers are filled with items from a database.
I want the small containers to use the full height but only the width they really need

How can I do this?

Comment: add a fixed height (height: 250px;) to parent container -.containerBig.

Comment: did that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

the big container always takes up the height of the small container that is having the Maximum height among the small containers.

If it is not taking the maximum height of the small containers then there is a float problem somewhere, This can be elminated by giving:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

either inside  the big container or before the big container

Answer (score 0):

See this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Exx/1/).

Replace 'abcdefghijkl' with your data. And the division will be stretched automatically to the data width with 100% height.

Comment: it just adds a scroll bar and uses the min-width. am i missing something?

Comment: you mean scroll bar in containerBig ?

Comment: have you put `overflow:auto`   ?

Comment: ok..I have made some changes in fiddle..see if working..if not , you and me both are mission something.

Comment: thanks for your help, but thats not the solution i need^^ i looked at your fiddle and if the text in the small container is longer it pushes the other containters down. thats what i dont want. i want that all small containers are in one row

Comment: But if the Main Container (containerBig) width is fixed, then obviously the small containers will go to next line if the data sizze is exceed. If you want to stretch the Maine division with small ones you have to give it a `min-width:940px;` and `overflow:auto;` .
And hope you got a better solution. :)

Comment: no i dont want the stretch the big container. i want the content in the small containers to make line breaks, so it fits in the small